# How to determine column order when using the table1 function

Tags: r

I am making a table with the table1 function, however it automatically arranges the rows alphabetically.I cant share the data unfortunately, but my current code looks something like this;

```r
table1(~ Running + Sitting + Yelling + drinking + Smoking | subject_condition, data=SDD)
```

I need to order the subject contrition columns in a specific way. I would greatly appreciate any help!!
Thank you Kindly :)

My data looks kinda like this:
[image]

The output has the columns by alphabetical order; Alabastor then Carlings then Bohemia. How do i edit the code so that the columns are arranged like this: Bohemia then carlings, then Alabastor?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't use that package, but it mentions `factor`s in `?table1`, so I wonder if you could convert one or more of the relevant columns into a `factor` (ordered).

Comment: can you simulate data and share that so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set and using the `gtsummary` package.
Initially species is in alphabetical order (first table) but if you refactor the variable it will appear in the order you like.

```
library(gtsummary)



tbl_summary(iris,
            by = "Species")

iris2 <- iris %>% 
          mutate(Species = factor(Species, levels =  c("versicolor", "setosa","virginica")))


tbl_summary(iris2,
            by = "Species")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got to factor the data in the respective column before you put it in table1; or you can do within table1.

```
table1(
data = datatable %>%
mutate(subjectcc = factor(subjectcc, levels = c("Alabastor",
"Carlings", "Bohemia"), ordered = T),
~Running +
Yelling +
Sitting +
Drinking +
Smoking | .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the `mappings` package. I've simulated some data to use for illustration.

```r
library(table1)
library(mappings)

# Simulate sample data
set.seed(123)
SDD <- expand.grid(Participant=1:4, subject_condition=c("Alabastor", "Carlings", "Bohemia"))
SDD$Running  <- sample(1:12, nrow(SDD), replace=T)
SDD$Sitting  <- sample(1:12, nrow(SDD), replace=T)
SDD$Yelling  <- sample(1:12, nrow(SDD), replace=T)
SDD$drinking <- sample(1:12, nrow(SDD), replace=T)
SDD$Smoking  <- sample(1:12, nrow(SDD), replace=T)


column_order <- mapping(c("Bohemia", "Carlings", "Alabastor"))

table1(~ Running + Sitting + Yelling + drinking + Smoking | column_order(subject_condition), data=SDD)
```

[image: example table result]